# Operating on Superclass Property with Subclass

Tags: matlab, class, oop, inheritance

To all,

I'm a novice programmer (I haven't taken a structured course) trying to pick up MATLAB. Currently, I'm trying to understand MATLAB's object-oriented programming tools. I want to cleanly divide up my project in the steps below. I would like to inherit the substantiated `data` and work on it in `validate`. I'm running into this error `You cannot set the read-only property 'data' of validations.`

How would I go about doing this? Would this be the appropriate way to organize myself in MATLAB?

```
classdef formatData.m 
    properties
        data = []
    end
    methods
        function formatData(data)
        % This should initialize the data
        end
        function columnShift(data)
        % Simple changes
        end
    end
end


classdef validateData.m < formatData
    properties
        error = logical(false)
    end
    methods
        function validateData(data)
            if nargin > 0
                obj.data = obj@formatData;
            end
        end
        function checkValues()
        % check values on data from formatData
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Apart from the constructor, the first argument to any (non static) method should be the object instance (usually `obj` or `self`) You may also be confusing variables passed in to methods as `data` and the `data` properties. Try changing your argument variables so they don't match property names then coding and error messages may become clearer? Finally, you given the code, but not the call that generates the error, that would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sad new is that MATLAB often changes the object-oriented codes. The code that I have posted is referenced from the latest documents. It seems completely different with a book that I have owned for one year.

```
classdef formatData

    properties
        data = [];
    end

    methods
        function obj = formatData(DataIn)
            %formatData This should initialize the data
            obj.data = DataIn;
        end

        function [DataOut] = columnShift(obj)
            %columnShift ? How to shift the column?
            DataOut = (obj.data)';
        end
    end
end


classdef validateData < formatData
    %validateData 

    properties
        error = false;
    end

    methods
        function obj = validateData(DataIn)
            %validateData 
            obj@formatData(DataIn);
        end

        function [] = checkValues(obj)
            %checkValues 

        end
    end
end
```